# fileReader on input change JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to read a file using the `fileReader` method and the `change` event on JQuery. But for some reason it isn't working.

http://jsfiddle.net/vnrcdn1q/13/

What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').on('change', function(e){

        var r = new FileReader();
        r.onload = function(e){
            console.log(r.result);
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try this? You are not calling `r.readAsText` that is why your onload function is not being triggered.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').on('change', function(evt){
        var f = evt.target.files[0]; 
        if (f){
        var r = new FileReader();
        r.onload = function(e){          
            console.log(e.target.result);
        };
            r.readAsText(f);
        } else 
        {
            console.log("failed");
        }
    });
});
```

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=wZLjbp74Xxk

Other than readAsText, there are other methods that you can use depending on how you want the uploaded file to be read.

**FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()**

> Starts reading the contents of the specified Blob, once finished, the result attribute contains an ArrayBuffer representing the file's
>   data.

**FileReader.readAsBinaryString()**

> Starts reading the contents of the specified Blob, once finished, the
>   result attribute contains the raw binary data from the file as a
>   string.

**FileReader.readAsDataURL()**

> Starts reading the contents of the specified Blob, once finished, the
>   result attribute contains a data: URL representing the file's data.

**FileReader.readAsText()**

> Starts reading the contents of the specified Blob, once finished, the
>   result attribute contains the contents of the file as a text string.

(Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Comment: Thanks, that really helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to tell the FileReader to actually try to read the file. So, after you set `r.onload`, you need to call `r.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0])`, `r.readAsBinaryString(this.files[0])`, `r.readAsDataURL(this.files[0])`, or `r.readAsText(this.files[0])` depending on what type of data you're trying to get out of the file. See this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#Methods) article on FileReader for descriptions of these different functions. Also, I would recommend wrapping all your FileReader code in a check to make sure there is at least one file selected. So, your code would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').on('change', function(e){
        if (this.files.length > 0){
            var r = new FileReader();
            r.onload = function(e){
                console.log(r.result);
            };
            // Call your chosen read function here
        }
    });
});
```